# Difference between these two cost functions?

Tags: machine-learning, logistic, loss-functions

There is the usual cross-entropy cost function: 
[image]

And then there is this cost function i stumbled upon in [this](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/232050328_Complete_solution_of_the_local_minima_in_the_XOR_problem) paper:
$$-\sum_{a}\sum_{k}ln[(O_{k}^{a})^{t^{a}_{k}}(1 - (O_{k}^{a} )^{1 - {t^{a}_{k}}}]$$

where $O$ are the activations and $t$ are the target values. 
What is the difference between these two?

Comment: They are the same. Just different notation. The h's correspond to the O's. i -> a, k -> k.

Comment: @jpmuc is there an added benefit of using the shorter variation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One is an average while the other is a sum. Otherwise, they're the same, just using different symbols.

Because they're the same (aside from the scalar $\frac{1}{m}$), there's no *mathematical* distinction between one and the other. Doing arithmetic on a computer would require special care, because floating point calculations can be fragile.